# How to prove that the average velocity is $0.5\alpha$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Question: Suppose $g$ is a constant. If $d(t) = 0.5gt^2$ represents the distance of a particle falling from rest at time $t$ ($t = 0$). Let the velocity after some time $T$ be given by $\alpha$. Prove the average velocity is $0.5\alpha$.

I am not exactly sure how to prove this, but here is my attempt.

If $d(t) = 0.5gt^2$, then the derivative of the function would be $v(t) = gt$. I am assuming this exercise is asking us to do this using the average function value, from $0$ to $\alpha$, in order to find the average velocity, so: $$v_{avg}(t) = \frac{1}{b - a}\int_{a}^{b} v(t) \ dt = \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\alpha gt \ dt = \frac{1}{\alpha}\left[\frac{1}{2}gt^2\right]_0^\alpha = 0.5g\alpha$$

This is what I got, and it is not the answer I am supposed to get. I would appreciate the assistance. Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: The a,b limits you use must be time-values, according with $dt$ inside the integral. Find $b=T$ for the given $\alpha$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The velocity $v$ at time $t$ is given by $d'(t)=v(t)=gt$.

At $t=T$ we get that $v(T)=gT=\alpha\implies g=\frac{\alpha}{T}$.

Therefore, $d(t)=\frac{\alpha}{2T}t^2$. To get the average speed we use $$v_\text{avg}=\frac{\frac{\alpha T}{2} - 0}{T-0}=\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

Comment: thank you very much